# Is there an easy way to add user roles for my slack bot(I'm using Bot framework 4 c#) or should I do it myself

Tags: c#, botframework, slack

I'm creating a slack bot that will interact with my own API, and I need my own roles for slack users that send command to API via my bot, are there ready-made solutions for this or I need to implement roles system for my bot myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no existing provision for this.

You can create a custom implementation to store userId with assigned roles.